# nfs server did not start anymore on fedora 25 after resent update

Tags: nfs, fedora

After an update today my nfs server did not respond anymore.

By trying to enable the services I got the following problems results:

```
sudo systemctl enable nfs-idmap.service
```

results to:

> The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, 
>   Alias
>   settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template   units).
>   This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
>   Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
>   1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
>      .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
>   2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
>      a requirement dependency on it.
>   3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
>      D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
>   4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
>      instance name specified.

The same for

```
sudo systemctl enable nfs-lock.service
sudo systemctl enable nfs.target
```

My installation is very long and updated from version to version of fedora. Maybe I have simply to use other services or changes in the config files?

I also tried to reinstall `nfs-utils` without success.

Comment: what did the log say ? Check for an error and show me what you got.

Comment: dmesg shows nothing. Where did nfs log?

Comment: The service should be `nfs-server.service` that you want to enable and start. If it is not there, search for nfs and install the nfs server package .

Answer (score 2):

You have almost certainly been bitten by the fact that the latest `nfs-utils` update (to the `nfs-utils-2.1.1-5.rc2.fc25` version) has disabled UDP support by default, which will break older clients or clients which have been forced to mount over UDP only.

The easy fix is to edit `/etc/sysconfig/nfs` and add `--udp` to `RPCNFSDARGS` and then restart the NFS server.